# How to download a div as image in word document using jquery.The div contais some diagram

Tags: jquery

How  to download a div as image in word document using jquery.The div contais some diagram

```js
here is my div.
<div id="genealogy" class="genealogy">
  </div>
am trying like that.But it displays only text  that present in the image not the image.
     $("#export").click(function(event) {
            $("#genealogy").wordExport();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) as an example on how to do it:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The .js files that it depends on, can also be found on that jsfiddle.

Just be careful with browser support.

You can adapt that code to get the PNG as a byte array/blob and then use [officegen](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen) to generate the doc.

Comment: Want to download as word document not as image.The image should be exported in word document.

Comment: Added more info on how you could do that.

Comment: The thing is that the image should be exported or saved in  word documnet format.